# How to get chunks from a stream obtained from a string not from a file (Node.js)

Tags: node.js

When using fs.createReadStream method in Node.js on a file, I get a readable stream, on which a 'data' event is emitted. So, later on I can call myReadableStream.on('data', (chunk) => { ... } ), where I can get chunks of my stream, so it won't overheat the memory. The thing is, how do I split a stream into chunks when stream is created from the string not from the file? Now, I have a string that I convert into a readable object using require('stream').Readable, but when I call on('data'), I get only 1 chunk (I assume that there was no 'data' event emitted on a string converted into a readable stream, wasn't it?). The value of  a stream derived from a file and of a stream derived from a string is the same (the same length), so I want it to be nicely split into a few chunks in order to speed up data processing. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I have answered my question.

To read from a file, I used

```
fs.createReadStream(path[, options])
```

method that returns a new ReadStream object ([doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)).

There are 4 types of streams in Node.js (Readable, Writable, Duples, and Transform) ([doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_types_of_streams)). Both Readable and Writable streams store data in an internal buffer. The amount of data potentially buffered depends on the **highWaterMark** option passed into the streams constructor.

For normal streams (those that are built from a string or from a Buffer object), the **highWaterMark** option specifies **a total number of bytes**. For streams operating in object mode (those that are build on Javascript object), the highWaterMark specifies a total number of objects.

From [Implementing a Readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_readable_stream) you can see that the **highWaterMark** value defaults to **16384 bytes** (or 16 KB) (for streams in object mode to 16 objects), and from [fs.createReadStream(path[, options])](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) method you can reveal that

> unlike the default value set for highWaterMark on a readable stream (16 kb), the stream returned by this method has a default value of 64 kb for the same parameter.

So, a ReadStream object returned by the fs.createReadStream(path[, options] method by default has a highWaterMark set to **65536 bytes** (64 KB).

Now I can check my code. The size of the string that I store into a file is **7372801 bytes**. When I read from this file using **fs.createReadStream(path[, options]** method, I get **113** chunks:

```
// To get a ReadStream object
fs.open(path, 'r', (err, fd) => { // fd - file descriptor
   if (err) {
      if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
         // path points to nowhere - file does not exist
      }
      throw err
   }

      var rStream = fs.createReadStream(path, {fd: fd})
})
```

By the way, here to read from a file I use a file descriptor. From the doc:

> If fd is specified, ReadStream will ignore the path argument and will use the specified file descriptor. This means that no 'open' event will be emitted. Note that fd should be blocking; non-blocking fds should be passed to net.Socket.

```
// To get number of chunks
var counter = 0

rStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
   counter++
})

rStream.on('end', () => {
   console.log('Total number of chunks: ' + counter)
})
```

This is because **7372801 / 65538 (64 KB) = 112 + remainder => 113** 
and when I artificially convert a string to a stream (you can find info how to do that in Implementing streams section from the docs, in my example I create a separate class):

```
const Readable = require('stream').Readable;
const util = require('util');

function MyReadable(str, options) {
   if (!(this instanceof MyReadable))
      return new MyReadable(str, options);
   Readable.call(this, options);
   this.str = str;
}
util.inherits(MyReadable, Readable);

MyReadable.prototype._read = function(size){
   var chunk = this.str.slice(0, size)
   if(chunk){
      this.str = this.str.slice(size)
      this.push(chunk)
   } else {
      this.push(null);
   }
}

module.exports = MyReadable; 

// Then 
var MyReadable = require('./filename')
var stream = new MyReadable(myString, {highWaterMark: 65536} ) // highWaterMark is in bytes
```

The above stream also gives 113 chunks since I re-set the **highWaterMark** option to 64KB.

In Node.js, to get the number of bytes in the string, you can use [Buffer.byteLength(string[, encoding])](http://Buffer.byteLength(string[,%20encoding])) method. Encoding defaults to 'utf8'.

To get a buffer from a Readable stream, you can use

```
rStream._readableState.buffer
```

from a Writable stream ->

```
wStream._writableState.getBuffer()
```

So, using a highWaterMark option now I can manage chunks.